# SSL certificate issues in multiple programs after letting IDE add a self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

Yesterday Visual Studio prompted me to add a self-signed certificate for `localhost` to enable security during local development.

Since then, I have been having significant issues with certificates in many programs on my computer.

**A few examples of problems include:**

Doing a google search from Chrome's new tab takes up to 30 seconds before finally going to google and showing the search results. During that delay, clicking the icon in the left of the address bar displays the message `Your connection to this site is not secure`.
When it finally goes to the google result page, the icon is a lock that says `Connection is secure` when clicked.

A Java command-line tool for AWS now throws the following error: `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.`

The program I use to connect to remote Git repositories, SourceTree, is unable to connect; it just gives the following error `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.`

**Is there a way to undo whatever Visual Studio did to cause all these SSL certificate issues?**

Edit: I've discovered that the SSL certificate issues are fixed when I connect to my work's VPN, but the issues still occur when I'm connected to my work's network via hard wire.

Comment: I will let you self-answer this question.  However, I will cleanup my own comments, since they are no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted my network administrator and they confirmed that the issue is due to a network configuration problem. I was selected to test a new network proxy and that's probably what's causing my problems.

The fact that it occurred just after installing certificates through Visual Studio was just a coincidence, the certificates on my computer seem to be working just fine when connected to different networks or when using a VPN.

Answer (score -1):

In Firefox: Using the hamburger menu, go to Options - Privacy & Security (scroll to the bottom)- Certificates - View Certificates
In Chrome: Using the three dot menu, go to Settings - Advanced - Privacy & Security - Manage Certificates